# Getting values from URL to JSF fields

Tags: jsf

I use,

- Java EE 7
- Payara 4.1.1
- JSF 2.2
- RichFaces 4.5.15
- PrimeFaces 6.0.

If I have this URL: `mysite.com/mypage.jsf?field1=value1&field2=value2`

I would like that, when the user typed this URL, I opened the `mypage.jsf`
with fields 1 and 2 filled with `value1` and `value2`.

- `<inputText id="field1" value="HOWTOGETFROMURL-value1"/>`
- `<inputText id="field2" value="HOWTOGETFROMURL-value2"/>`

Comment: RichFaces and PrimeFaces together?

Comment: Yes, both works fine in JSF 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to catch any parameter from the url is to use `metadata` and `viewParam`  tags in the head of the page in the url.

So in your mypage.jsf, the tags will be :

```
<h:head>
....
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="field1" value="#{yourManagedBean.field1}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="field2" value="#{yourManagedBean.field2}"/>
</f:metadata>
</h:head>
```

Your managed bean must have attributes to receive the values from Url.

and the inputs will be :

```
<h:inputText id="field1" value="#{yourManagedBean.field1}"/>
<h:inputText id="field2" value="#{yourManagedBean.field2}"/>
```

I hope it helps.